# Allow onclick just once

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-click-event

In order to add a very long list of option elements to a select list I add them on-click. I want to prevent that the list is added multiple times. How can I do that?

```
$("#skiresort").click(function(){
$("#skiresort").load("/v3/inc/review.php");
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a method for executing an event handler only once: [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$("#skiresort").one('click', function(){
    $("#skiresort").load("/v3/inc/review.php");
});
```

Comment: I want to prevent clicking on the same button again but if user clicks another button then the previous button should be clickable....How to do it?

Comment: @Uday: You can use a shared variable which holds a reference to the last clicked button and compare against it.

Comment: Yeah. I did that finally. I though if there could be any function for that.

Answer (score 2):

Felix answer is perfect for jQuery, I'm adding this just to show a generic JavaScript technique for it:

```
function runOnce(f) {
   var called = false;
   return function() {
     if (!called) {
       called = true;
       return f.apply(this, arguments);
     }
   };
 }
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
var myNewFunction = runOnce(myFunction); // this does not run "myFunction", but returns a new one that will only run once.

myNewFunction(1, 2, 3); // runs the "myFunction" and returns whatever it returns
myNewFunction(1, 2, 3); // doesn't do anything, just returns undefined
```